# How do I access "Applications"?

Tags: appmenu

Okay, I'll just go ahead and be stupid. I want to disable Image Checksum in Brasero, and I have found a few instructions like this:

http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/disable-annoying-creating-image-checksum-in-brasero-after-ubuntu-10-10-upgrade/

which tell me to go to Applications > Brasero (etc.).

I... don't know how to go to Applications. So far, everything I've done in Ubuntu either works via the terminal or via the Ubuntu main menu (the power on/off button on the top right of the screen which gives me access to Startup Applications but not much else). How do I access this Applications menu as referenced in the above?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 12.04. Maybe I'm not as stupid as I thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Ubuntu in that article is outdated. In newer versions of Ubuntu, (11.04 and onwards) Unity is the default (pre-installed) DE.

### How to access an application with the dash:

1. Click on the dash (it looks like an Ubuntu logo).
2. Click on the applications button. In older versions of Ubuntu, such as 12.04 like you're using, there is simply a drop-down menu.
3. Click on which application you want to launch (in this case, Brasero). You may also type in what you're looking for, and the Dash will bring up relevant results.

[image: Visual demonstration of finding applications with the Dash]

---

As for Checksums in Brasero, you may disable the feature by naviagating to **Edit -> Plugins**, then un-checking the **File Checksum** option.

[image: Visualization of Brasero dialog]

Answer (score 1):

That article has written in 2010 and based on Ubuntu Old versions which are with Classic look. But current Ubuntu using Unity Desktop.Here you can launch it directly from unity dash,type as  Brasero in the Unity dash.
For Example:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. *(Super is the button with Windows/Ubuntu logo on it)*. Here you can see all your installed applications. You can even filter the result by *Type, Rating and Source.*

[image: Sidebar]